# Compare two identical json lists with objects and fields within objects in different order

Tags: java, junit

I am trying to write a unit test using JUnit, I want to test a function using AssertsEqual where I have two lists of JsonObjects. Below are my actual and expected json Strings.

```
String jsonOutput = [ {
                       id: 1,
                       name: abc,
                       age: 23
                      },
                      {
                       id: 2,
                       name: efg,
                       age: 26
                      },
                      {
                       id: 3,
                       name: rst,
                       age: 26
                      }
     ]


   String jsonExpected = [ {
                            id: 2,
                            name: efg,
                            age: 26
                           },
                           {  
                            id: 1,
                            age: 23,
                            name: abc
                           },
                           {
                            id: 3,
                            name: rst,
                            age: 26
                           }
             ]
```

In the example above, it can seen that the object order is changed for the expected string and order of the individual fields is also changed within the individual objects.

Please find my test case below:

```
   @Test
public void testApply() {
    Command command = new Command();
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Command.class.getName());
    command.set(logger, new JsonObject());
    command.apply(Buffer.buffer(TestConstants.ALL_GAPS));
    Object eventList = command.apply(Buffer.buffer(TestConstants.OCCUPIED_GAPS)); // returns a list of json objects
    List<JsonObject> expectedList = createExpectedEventList(TestConstants.EVENT_LIST);
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedList, eventList);
}

private List<JsonObject> createExpectedEventList(String eventListString) {
    JsonArray eventArray = new JsonArray(eventListString);
    List<JsonObject> eventList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Object obj : eventArray) {
        eventList.add((JsonObject) obj);
    }
    return eventList;
}


    Assert.assertEquals(expectedList, eventList);
```

The above function returns false even if the same string is provided changing the order. I want this function to return as true if the contents of string are same irrespective of the order.

Comment: *what have you tried so far?* show us some code please

Comment: Unit test case added.

Comment: While I understand what you are trying to do here, I am concerned you are missing a pretty critical piece of information.  Json arrays which are ordered different are _not_ equal.

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked JSONUnit?

https://github.com/lukas-krecan/JsonUnit

It's description is:

> JsonUnit is a library that simplifies JSON comparison in unit tests.

If you are using Maven you could create a project like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.fernandes</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsonunit.test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.javacrumbs.json-unit</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-unit</artifactId>
            <version>1.25.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0-M4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Then you can write a JUnit test like this one here:

```
package com.fernandes.jsonunit.test;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static net.javacrumbs.jsonunit.JsonAssert.assertJsonEquals;
import static net.javacrumbs.jsonunit.JsonAssert.when;
import static net.javacrumbs.jsonunit.core.Option.IGNORING_ARRAY_ORDER;

/**
 * Created by Gil on 26/07/2017.
 */
public class ArraysTest {

    @Test
    void checkArrays() {
        String array1 = "{\"test\":[4,1,2,3]}";
        String array2 = "{\"test\":[1,2,3,4]}";
        assertJsonEquals(array1, array2, when(IGNORING_ARRAY_ORDER));
    }
}
```

OK, if you cannot use JSON Unit you could try to hash the content of the JSON lists you want to compare, sort the hashes and then compare the hash lists. Here is a quick example using Jackson, JUnit 5 and Java 8:

```
@Test
@DisplayName("When arrays equal, but in different order - match")
void checkArraysManual() throws IOException {
    String array1 = "[{\n" +
            "\"id\": 1,\n" +
            "\"name\": \"abc\",\n" +
            "\"age\": 23\n" +
            "},\n" +
            "{\n" +
            "\"id\": 2,\n" +
            "\"name\": \"efg\",\n" +
            "\"age\": 26\n" +
            "},\n" +
            "{\n" +
            "\"id\": 3,\n" +
            "\"name\": \"rst\",\n" +
            "\"age\": 26\n" +
            "}]";

    String array2 = "[{\n" +
            "\"id\": 2,\n" +
            "\"name\": \"efg\",\n" +
            "\"age\": 26\n" +
            "},\n" +
            "{\n" +
            "\"id\": 1,\n" +
            "\"name\": \"abc\",\n" +
            "\"age\": 23\n" +
            "},\n" +
            "{\n" +
            "\"id\": 3,\n" +
            "\"name\": \"rst\",\n" +
            "\"age\": 26\n" +
            "}]";

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode root1 = mapper.readTree(array1);
    JsonNode root2 = mapper.readTree(array2);
    ArrayNode array1Node = (ArrayNode) root1;
    ArrayNode array2Node = (ArrayNode) root2;
    assertThat(compareArrayNodes(array1Node, array2Node), is(true));
}

private boolean compareArrayNodes(ArrayNode array1Node, ArrayNode array2Node) {
    if(array1Node.size() != array2Node.size()) {
        return false;
    }
    List<Integer> hashList1 = hashArrayNode(array1Node);
    List<Integer> hashList2 = hashArrayNode(array2Node);
    return hashList1.equals(hashList2);
}

private List<Integer> hashArrayNode(ArrayNode array1Node) {
    Iterable<JsonNode> supplier = array1Node::elements;
    return StreamSupport.stream(supplier.spliterator(), false)
            .map(Objects::hashCode).sorted()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I came across this library but I am in need of a solution without adding additional dependencies.

Comment: This is a bit of a shame. It just seemed to me that your requirements are a perfect fit for this library. It can deal with list comparisons "irrespective of the order", like you requested.

Comment: I perfectly agree with your solution, but I am just bounded to add additional dependencies :)

Comment: My suggestion would be then to sort the arrays by id, before you execute your assertions. That should guarantee a successful assertion in case of equality. Actually this is what is suggested in the other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45329517/2735286

Comment: What about sorting the fields within the JsonObjects ?

Comment: I have added another suggestion on how you can solve the problem to my answer. Basically I get both lists, hash these, sort the hash lists and finally compare the hash lists. See, if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Two options off the top of my head:

Throw them all into a `Set`, and compare the sets:

```
Set<Foo> a = new HashSet<>(first);
Set<Foo> b = new HashSet<>(second);
assertEquals(a, b);
```

This won't work if your lists contain duplicates.

---

Alternatively, just sort the lists before you compare. Any arbitrary sorting will work, provided its consistent.

```
List<Foo> a = Collections.sort(new ArrayList<>(first));
List<Foo> b = Collections.sort(new ArrayList<>(second));
assertEquals(a, b);
```

Comment: Unit test case added, could you take a look ?

Comment: Cannot use Collections.sort as the 'Foo' (JsonObject) is not comparable.

Comment: Ah. That's a pain. Convert them to strings first.